# Find asp hiddenfield in jquery script file

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I had a hidden field like  this

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfprdid" value="hooray" runat="server" />
```

and I am trying to acces its value from a jquery file like this

```
alert($("#'<%=hfprdid.ClientID %>'").value);
```

but this throws an error like this

```
Error: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #'<%=hfprdid.ClientID %>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
alert($("#<%= hfprdid.ClientID %>").val());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the double quotes and change to single quotes

```
alert($('#<%= hfprdid.ClientID %>').value);
```

Comment: I think you have to use single-quotes, as inline expressions tend to work bad when enclosed in double-quotes.

Comment: as AV pointed out you probably wanted `.val()` instead of `value`